# How to choice correct value max_connections of postgres on google cloud

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, typeorm, google-cloud-sql

I use postgres cloud on google. When i create postgres with default config if mutiple user connect (example : 10 user) it allway throw me error

```
remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections
sorry, too many clients already :: proc.c:360
```

When i **max_connections = 300** it ok. Error not throw. But i confused why google postgres not scale max connection when number user increase.

**I have a question :**
Why application always throw error sorry, too many clients already if i not set value **max_connections** ?
When my application on production, how to know max number connection access one time ? If i not set default max_connections what number default **max_connections** of postgres ?

Comment: You only need one connection to the database. I use connection pooling so that connections are recycled. Scalable designs do not continuously open additional new connections. If you have designed your software correctly, 4 connections is enough even for 10,000 users.

Comment: @JohnHanley thanks for answer. If i think correct, it mean my code not close correct connection when it open connection into database. How to check connection not close ? I plan use idleTimeoutMillis set timeout if connect not close

Comment: Do a code review. I don't think idleTimeoutMillis will help you.

Comment: I have provided an answer below.please check and let me know if the below suggestions were helpful

Answer (score 2):

When you don’t set the max_connections the system uses the default value. If the default connection value is not sufficient you will receive an error. The default is typically 100 connections. As
mentioned in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/quotas#postgresql)

> max_connections automatically calculated, when you create a Cloud SQL for PostgreSQL instance, the machine type configuration settings automatically adjust the range of memory sizes available, based on the number of cores you select. This also determines the initial default connection limits set for the instance.
>
> You can find the connection limits for your instance by connecting to your database and running this command:
>
> `SELECT * FROM pg_settings WHERE name = 'max_connections';`
>
> To determine the maximum value that you can set for this flag, you must first calculate the number of backend connections that are already in use. This calculation is the sum of the values for max_connections (maximum number of client connections), autovacuum_max_workers (maximum number of autovacuum processes), and max_worker_processes. The sum cannot exceed 262142.